# Ember FastBoot Cannot read property 'userAgent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to use `Ember FastBoot` for my application but when I run:
`ember fastboot --serve-assets` this error is thrown:

`Cannot read property 'userAgent' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userAgent' of undefined
    at Object.125.global/document (<anonymous>:121923:53)
    at s (<anonymous>:104896:621)
    at <anonymous>:104896:672
    at Object.106../big-play-button.js (<anonymous>:113849:23)
    at s (<anonymous>:104896:621)
    at <anonymous>:104896:672
    at Object.139.../../src/js/utils/merge-options.js (<anonymous>:123824:15)
    at s (<anonymous>:104896:621)
    at e (<anonymous>:104896:792)
    at <anonymous>:104896:810`

any help?

Comment: Can you post the code in `big-play-button.js` - it looks like you your JavaScript is relying on a global variable like `document` that is undefined when running FastBoot since the rendering doesn't happen within the context of a browser.

Comment: @OrenHizkiya https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/src/js/big-play-button.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo you posted contains a number of references to `document` and `window`. You will have to use the [ember provided facility for detecting the current `environment` details](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/environment.js) and implement conditional logic based on whether your pages are being rendered in the browser or not. You can use `environment.hasDOM` to perform that check.

Comment: This is a component installed with bower, as I understand, I would have to rewrite it in order to use with ember fast boot right?

Comment: bad news for me but anyway thank you for figuring this out.